# df.ix gets NAN as subset

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, subset

I have a dataframe like below [72 rows x 25 columns]:

```
     Pin      CPULabel   Freq(MHz) DCycle     Skew(1-3)min Skew(1-3)mean
0    Dif0    BP100_Fast   99.9843  0.492            0             0   
1    Dif0    BP100_Slow   100.011  0.493            0             0   
2    Dif0  100HiBW_Fast   100.006  0.503            0             0   
3    Dif0  100HiBW_Slow   100.007  0.504            0             0   
4    Dif0  100LoBW_Fast   100.005  0.503            0             0   
5    Dif0  100LoBW_Slow   99.9951  0.504            0             0   
8    Dif1    BP100_Fast   99.9928  0.492            7            10   
9    Dif1    BP100_Slow   99.9962  0.492           11            12   
10   Dif1  100HiBW_Fast   100.014  0.502           10            11   
11   Dif1  100HiBW_Slow   100.006  0.503            6            13   
12   Dif1  100LoBW_Fast   99.9965  0.502            5            10   
13   Dif1  100LoBW_Slow   99.9946  0.503           12            14   
16   Dif2    BP100_Fast   99.9929  0.493            2             6   
17   Dif2    BP100_Slow    99.997  0.493            8            13   
18   Dif2  100HiBW_Fast   100.002  0.504            4             9   
19   Dif2  100HiBW_Slow   99.9964  0.504           13            17   
20   Dif2  100LoBW_Fast   100.021  0.504            8             9
```

I am just interested in the rows which contain BP100_Fast, 100HiBW and 100HiBW strings. So I used the the command below:

```
excel = pd.read_excel('25C_3.3V.xlsx', skiprows=1)
excel.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
general = excel[excel['Pin'] != 'Clkin']
general.drop_duplicates(keep=False, inplace=True)
slew = general[(general['CPULabel']=='BP100_Fast') | (general['CPULabel']=='100LoBW_Fast') | (general['CPULabel']=='100HiBW_Fast')]
```

I am able to get what I want[36 rows x 25 columns]:

```
      Pin     CPULabel   Freq(MHz) DCycle      Skew(1-3)min Skew(1-3)mean  
0    Dif0    BP100_Fast   99.9843  0.492            0             0   
2    Dif0  100HiBW_Fast   100.006  0.503            0             0   
4    Dif0  100LoBW_Fast   100.005  0.503            0             0   
8    Dif1    BP100_Fast   99.9928  0.492            7            10   
10   Dif1  100HiBW_Fast   100.014  0.502           10            11   
12   Dif1  100LoBW_Fast   99.9965  0.502            5            10   
16   Dif2    BP100_Fast   99.9929  0.493            2             6   
18   Dif2  100HiBW_Fast   100.002  0.504            4             9   
20   Dif2  100LoBW_Fast   100.021  0.504            8             9
```

However, if I changed the last command:

```
slew = general.ix[['BP100_Fast', '100LoBW_Fast', '100HiBW_Fast'], :]
```

I got NAN as my result. [3 rows x 25 columns]

```
              Pin    CPULabel  Freq(MHz) DCycle Skew(1-3)min Skew(1-3)mean
BP100_Fast    NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN        NaN          NaN   
100LoBW_Fast  NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN        NaN          NaN   
100HiBW_Fast  NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN        NaN          NaN
```

Is there any way to complete this with df.ix? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Per Docs**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix)

> The .ix indexer is deprecated, in favor of the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers. .ix offers a lot of magic on the inference of what the user wants to do. To wit, .ix can decide to index positionally OR via labels, depending on the data type of the index. This has caused quite a bit of user confusion over the years. The full indexing documentation is here. (GH14218)

**Option 1**
`isin`

```
general[general.CPULabel.isin(['BP100_Fast', '100LoBW_Fast', '100HiBW_Fast'])]

     Pin      CPULabel  Freq(MHz)  DCycle  Skew(1-3)min  Skew(1-3)mean
0   Dif0    BP100_Fast    99.9843   0.492             0              0
2   Dif0  100HiBW_Fast   100.0060   0.503             0              0
4   Dif0  100LoBW_Fast   100.0050   0.503             0              0
8   Dif1    BP100_Fast    99.9928   0.492             7             10
10  Dif1  100HiBW_Fast   100.0140   0.502            10             11
12  Dif1  100LoBW_Fast    99.9965   0.502             5             10
16  Dif2    BP100_Fast    99.9929   0.493             2              6
18  Dif2  100HiBW_Fast   100.0020   0.504             4              9
20  Dif2  100LoBW_Fast   100.0210   0.504             8              9
```

---

**Option 2**
`query`

```
general.query('CPULabel in ["BP100_Fast", "100LoBW_Fast", "100HiBW_Fast"]')

     Pin      CPULabel  Freq(MHz)  DCycle  Skew(1-3)min  Skew(1-3)mean
0   Dif0    BP100_Fast    99.9843   0.492             0              0
2   Dif0  100HiBW_Fast   100.0060   0.503             0              0
4   Dif0  100LoBW_Fast   100.0050   0.503             0              0
8   Dif1    BP100_Fast    99.9928   0.492             7             10
10  Dif1  100HiBW_Fast   100.0140   0.502            10             11
12  Dif1  100LoBW_Fast    99.9965   0.502             5             10
16  Dif2    BP100_Fast    99.9929   0.493             2              6
18  Dif2  100HiBW_Fast   100.0020   0.504             4              9
20  Dif2  100LoBW_Fast   100.0210   0.504             8              9
```

---

**Option 3**
`pd.Series.str.endswith`

```
 general[general.CPULabel.str.endswith('Fast')]

     Pin      CPULabel  Freq(MHz)  DCycle  Skew(1-3)min  Skew(1-3)mean
0   Dif0    BP100_Fast    99.9843   0.492             0              0
2   Dif0  100HiBW_Fast   100.0060   0.503             0              0
4   Dif0  100LoBW_Fast   100.0050   0.503             0              0
8   Dif1    BP100_Fast    99.9928   0.492             7             10
10  Dif1  100HiBW_Fast   100.0140   0.502            10             11
12  Dif1  100LoBW_Fast    99.9965   0.502             5             10
16  Dif2    BP100_Fast    99.9929   0.493             2              6
18  Dif2  100HiBW_Fast   100.0020   0.504             4              9
20  Dif2  100LoBW_Fast   100.0210   0.504             8              9
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach:

```
labels = ['BP100_Fast', '100HiBW', '100HiBW']

slew = \
pd.read_excel('25C_3.3V.xlsx', skiprows=1) \
  .fillna(value=0) \
  .query("Pin != Clkin and CPULabel in @labels") \
  .drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

alternatively you can change:

```
slew = general.ix[['BP100_Fast', '100LoBW_Fast', '100HiBW_Fast'], :]
```

to:

```
slew = general.loc[general['CPULabel'].isin(['BP100_Fast','100LoBW_Fast','100HiBW_Fast'])]
```